CLI alternative(s) to UbuntuStudio Controls? (20.04.3 LTS)
I run UbuntuStudio 20.04.3 on a somewhat old Macbook (2013), and was listening to some music through my external SuperDrive, which I doubt is as relevant as what I was using for sound output: Thunderbolt 2 port connected to the HDMI input on my soundbar (LG).
All fine for about 10 minutes, and then the connection to the soundbar reverts to the Macbook default speaker. Annoying, yes, but using the Ubuntu Studio controls app I was able to re-establish the connection without having to dig too deeply.
Now I don't expect great miracles in helping me troubleshoot WHY this is happening and preventing it.
BUT, if I could instead use a CLI alternative that would re-establish the HDMI connection (the soundbar isn't powering down, it stays on with the HDMI input indicator light), that would be a decent work-around.
The reason I ask about CLI is that the Macbook might be across the room (I'm lazy) or upstairs in the loft, and I can keep an SSH session open on my other laptop (already successfully set up).
Can you point me in the direction of the CLI tools that can perform the same functions? I figure the Ubuntu Studio Controls app is just a GUI for scriptable tools, right?pactl | grep 5.1
Thanks if you can help,
Whiskey Fungus Dude
Addendum: output of pactl | grep 5.1 :
    Description: Built-in Audio Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)
    device.profile.description = "Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)"
Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)
    device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)"
Volume: front-left: 58190 /  89% / -3.10 dB,   front-right: 58190 /  89% / -3.10 dB
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 33568, available: yes)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)


Would it work to use ssh -X and use the GUI app?

Possibly, but that seems like it would be a little slower and use a little bit more sys overhead.  Plus I'm wondering if I can eventually turn a CLI-based solution into a scripted preventive. I.e., since it seems like this is happening pretty consistently after 10 minutes of output to the soundbar, I might be able to automate the re-establishment of the connection (?).
That's assuming that whatever is causing the 10 minute remains a deep mystery encoded in depths I'll likely never succeed in plumbing...

Have you tried other versions of Ubuntu like 22.04? Perhaps you can run it in a live session for more than 10 minutes and check out if the issue is there

I do have the 22.04 of UbuntuStudio, so yes, trying that is next, thanks. The only thing stopping me from committing to it is that I have a lot of Audacity projects that are still in the old file format from pre-3 versions. And I've been reading about numerous buggy issues on their forum, so I'm happy with the stability I'm currently enjoying.  OTOH I suppose I could uninstall the > 3.4 that's bundled with US 22.04, and "down"grade back to old familiar.

Anyway, I feel like I'm in lukewarm pursuit of my solution via pactl

Update: same Macbook, different distro (installed on another partition, not live--AV Linux/MX Linux 23.1) connected to soundbar in exact same way, no timeout. Still Pulseaudio.
